# How to add one more dtd to my Spring configration file?

Tags: spring, aspectj, dtd, xml

I have use a .dtd to my applicationContext.xml, but now i want to use Spring's AOP based on annotation. I've been told to add a  in my applicationContext.xml.

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
...
```

But something wrong happens. It seems that the file doesn't recognize the aop node, so i think i should import one more .dtd file, and i find this:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
```

but can i use both .dtd togeter? how?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `DOCTYPE` here, better declare xml namespaces like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<beans>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
...
```

`xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` means that `beans` will be root namespace (you don't have to use `<beans:bean>`) and `aop` will be accesible as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The two DTDs you cite are not constructed in a way that allows them to be used together.  In particular, the definition of `beans` in http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd is just

```
<!ELEMENT beans (
              description?,
              (import | alias | bean)*
)>
```

It does not provide for a child named `aop:aspectj-autoproxy`, and it doesn't provide any mechanism for later users like you to add new things to the content of `beans`.

DTDs can be built for extensibility and to support the integration of elements from multiple namespaces, though it requires a bit of forethought and planning.  When extension points are not included, it's typically pretty hard or impossible to extend the DTD without just rewriting it.